How to call in template a function with different amount of arguments?
I want my template to take lambdas with different number of parameters and be able to handle them.
In the code below template process takes callable object (function) but doesn’t know whether passed lambda takes arguments or not. Can I somehow check this in template and make the respective call?
void process(auto fn) {
    [[maybe_unused]] float res = fn(2.0f);

    // Is there a chance to make something like:
    // float res = takes-no-args<fn>() ? fn() : fn(2.0f);

    // do something with res...
}

int main() {
    // This is the default usage
    process([](float arg) { return arg; });

    // I want to be able to make such a call
    process([]() { return 1.0f; });

    // Possible, but verbose workaround
    process([](float) { return 1.0f; });
}

Demo
A simple workaround would be to always pass the lambda with the same signature and ignore the provided argument, but this is way too verbose in case of many arguments.
The goal is to keep client code as simple and clean as possible.

@Mat, ops. Thank you for catching this. I slightly "over-complicated" the things, focusing on another point. The code has been updated. Still want to get rid of this float in argument. Is this possible>

@DamirTenishev Doesn't my answer solve that issue?

@TedLyngmo, thank you so much, I am looking into it now. I just didn't notice the update on the page when I was writing the comment to Mat.

@DamirTenishev :-) I see. Ok, hope it works for your case!

@TedLyngmo, thank you again. Worked like a charm! Let me wait a day for possible better answers (like SO recommends) and I will mark the answer as accepted.

@DamirTenishev Glad to hear it! Sure, let it rest a bit. No hurry.


Is there a chance to make something like:
float res = takes-no-args<fn>() ? fn() : fn(2.0f);

Yes, takes-no-args<fn>() exists in the family of std::is_invocable type traits, so you could check if fn is invokable without arguments by using constexpr-if like this:
#include <type_traits>

void process(auto fn) {
    float res;
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_r_v<float, decltype(fn)>) {
        res = fn(); // invokable without arguments
    } else {
        res = fn(2.0f);
    }
    // do something with res...
}

For something more complex than a float, you might not want to default construct it first, so you could for example use an immediately invoked lambda to avoid that:
void process(auto fn) {
    float res = [&]{
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_r_v<float, decltype(fn)>) {
            return fn();
        } else {
            return fn(2.0f);        
        }
    }();
    // do something with res...
}


Thank you again. I totally forgot about decltype. When got your solution, just out of curiosity tried to "simplify" it (in terms of used language constructs), just comparing types, but failed: demo. Is it still possible just to compare types in this or close way or there is something in the way to do so? I am not saying that your solution is not simple or straightforward (it is), I am just curious, if this could be done in this way.

@DamirTenishev You're welcome! For that comparison to work, you'd have to compare with a function pointer (float(*)()) - but then comes the problem with each lambda being a unique type, so that wouldn't match the check automatically. You could use a unary + to let captureless lambdas decay into regular function pointers (example) but the function now becomes a bit fragile and probably rejects code that you want to work :)
